# Table not working as attribute in my class

Tags: lua

I have a situation like this:

```
TestClass = { param = { n = 5 } }
function TestClass:new(o)
    o = o or {}
    setmetatable(o, self)
    self.__index = self
    return o
end
function TestClass:update(n)
    n = n or 1
    self.param.n = self.param.n + n
end
```

The issue is that when I instantiate an object like: `obj = TestClass:new()` the update method doesn't update the value stored in the `obj` table but instead it changes the value inside the default table: `TestClass`

Is there a way to fix this? I already looked up the [tutorial](https://www.lua.org/pil/16.1.html) by the creators of lua but they say nothing about tables as attributes.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should do it like this then:

```
function TestClass:new(o)
    o = o or { param = { n = 5 } }
    setmetatable(o, self)
    self.__index = self
    return o
end
```

Comment: Thanks. At the time of your post I was already posting my solution but I decided to put your name along with the user that helped me on reddit for credit.

Answer (score 0):

I solved this and the problem was that tables are stored by reference, not value so the solution was to create the table inside the `o` object at the time of instancing (the `TestClass:new()` method).

To do this automatically and only for params that are not passed in I wrote this little function:

```
function setDefaults(o, def)
    for k,v in pairs(def) do
        o[k] = o[k] or v
    end
end
```

And it is simply used like this:

```
function TestClass:new(o)
    o = o or {}
    setDefaults(o, {
        param = { n = 5 }
    })
    setmetatable(o, self)
    self.__index = self
    return o
end
```

I also wanted to thank a lot [u/JackMacWindowsLinux](https://www.reddit.com/user/JackMacWindowsLinux/) and Ivo Beckers for helping me find this solution.